# jQuery Mobile Alert if navbar ID is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery, jquery-mobile-navbar

I am trying to revise the following jQuery Mobile code to display if the navbar with the id "e" is clicked. The code below works for all of the navbar items, but I only want the alert to appear if the navbar with the id "e" is clicked. Any help revising this would be great. Thanks much!

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#p_page', function(event){       
    $('div[data-role="navbar"] a').live('click', function () {

        alert("div E clicked");
});       
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#p_page', function(event){       
    $('div[data-role="navbar"] ul li a#e').on('click', function () {
        alert("div E clicked");
    });       
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/rnRqm/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `live` use `click` event because live is deprecated from jquery.

```
 $('div[data-role="navbar"] a').on('click', function () {
      alert("div E clicked");
 });
```